# sed: find and replace a string (with characters like $ and space) in a binary file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file, where there is a string like `tail +390 $0 > $outname`. I need to find this line and replace it with `tail -n +390 $0 > $outname`. I am trying with `sed` like this --

```
sed -i -e 's/tail +390 \$0 > \$outname/tail -n +390 \$ > \$outname' file.bin ;
```

and

```
sed -i -e 's/tail\ +390\ \$0\ >\ \$outname/tail\ -n\ +390\ \$\ > \$outname' file.bin ;
```

The file that I am trying to modify is a binary file.

But I can not get it work, any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `/` at the last because your sed syntax is incorrect. It's like `s/search/replace` but it should be `s/search/replace/optional-modifiers` .

```
sed -i 's/tail +390 \$0 > \$outname/tail -n +390 \$0 > \$outname/' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'tail +390 $0 > $outname' | sed 's/tail +390 \$0 > \$outname/tail -n +390 \$0 > \$outname/'
tail -n +390 $0 > $outname
```